# Reading user input without halting execution

Tags: events, event-handling, lua, minecraft

I'm trying to read user input in a console interface in a Lua application.
However, I do not want to halt program execution as the title suggests. Using read() would interfere with the normal handling of ongoing events, and interface updates, while the user's typing.

The best solution I could come up with was maintaining a temporary variable I apply any user input to that isn't a function key. However, my event handler returns scancodes, and I know of no way to map these to ASCII codes short of maintaining a table for each key, which is something I really want to avoid.

Any ideas?

Edit
To give an example of what I mean:

```
function read_input()
 local input = read()
 do_something_with(input)
end
while true do
 e,param1,param2,param3 = os.pullEvent()
 if (e=='key' and param1=='201') then
  read_input()
 elseif (e=='something_else') then
  do_something_else()
 end
end
```

As you can see, the user can at some point land in a function demanding user input. While this input is taken, I can't have any other (event-based) functions of the program being impeded by this.

Comment: Where are you getting this `os.pullEvent` function from?

Comment: Its computercraft. a minecraft mod

Comment: Try using `coroutines` or if minecraft provides something similar timer-based event handler.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do while getting user input?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to read the keys continuously from the os.pullEvent()

```
local input
while true do
  e,param1,param2,param3 = os.pullEvent()
  if (e=='key') then
    -- do some fancy stuff for checking which key has pressed and append it to input
    -- additionally if it's enter do something other fancy
  else
    -- blah blah
  end
end
```

I'm not sure but I thought the character of which key was pressed is in one of the params of the pullEvent, I might be mistaken tho.

Additionally if you want to do something every second or so, start a timer which also fires the pullEvent.